# Problems displaying AdMob in the bottom of a relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have problems with this special case, I need to tell my relativelayout that it is divided in two portions, one portion must be 80% of the height of the screen and it is a scroll grid view with images. The other percentage must be for the Admob banner.

The problem is that when this app is loaded in devices with low resolution, the Admob banner is not being displayed. I think because the height of the add is more than the height of the banner container in my layout.

What is the correct way to do this? I tried putting MATCH_PARENT in the height of my gridView and WRAP_CONTENT and ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM combined with BELOW, GridView but does not works, the add is not displayed on the screen, I think because of the MATCH PARENT of the gridview.

This is some of my code:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));     
        setContentView(mainLayout); 

gridView = new GridView(this);
        gridView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        gridView.setId(1);
mainLayout.addView(gridView);   

adViewContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
        adViewContainer.setId(2);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adViewContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adViewContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);
        mainLayout.addView(adViewContainer, adViewContainerParams);
```

I tried putting 80% of the height to the gridView and 20% to the banner but then when the app is displayed in low resolution devices, the banner is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout structure should be below:

```
// Root view 
<LinearLayout ...>

    <GridView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <AdView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default size of the admob add banner? Make your add container height to wrap content, give it alignparentbottom to true and put layout_above in gridview and give id of the add container. Make sure you first declare the ad container and then declare the gridview.